# How to change control scheme on Lego Games

Tags: lego-star-wars, lego-marvel-super-heroes

For quite a long time I've had an extremely vexing problem on Lego Marvel Super Heroes for Xbox 360.  When playing split screen co-op, one controller has the thumbsticks configured right handed, and the other has them reversed (left handed).  I thought maybe I'd just accidentally switch them in the settings somewhere, but I couldn't find any option to change them.  I also looked into my console settings, but on 360 I don't seem to have the option to change.  **Is there any way to change this setting to make both controllers right handed?**

I had thought there might just be something weird with this one game on XBox 360, so I later moved on to playing Lego Marvel Avengers on XBox One and never had the same issue.  I recently attempted to play Lego Star Wars: The Complete Saga on my XBox One (note: a totally different console) - and I experienced ***the same issue***.  I do not experience this issue with any other games on my XBox 360 or XBox One.  I've combed the internet and can't find any reference to anyone having a similar issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you need to do to to fix the problem on Xbox One:

- Press both the 2 small round buttons below the big button in the middle of the controller. This will bring up the Xbox 360 settings.
- go to settings tab - profile - game defaults - action.
- here you can switch the settings for the controller. Just switch the movement to the left stick instead of the right stick.

I'm sure the process is similar for fixing the problem on 360. This was killing me for a long time! In fact I uninstalled the game due to this issue but recently reinstalled it for my son and was able to fix the problem ( by pure luck of hitting both buttons at the same time). Doesn't help that there is pretty much nothing online that tells you about or how to fix this issue.

Comment: Joey I'll give you the bounty in 24 hours when I'm allowed.  I hope you come back for it.  Thanks so much for a solution to a problem that has haunted me for such a long time.  Numerous games will now once again be playable.  Huzzah!